# Procedural Question on Plugin Installation

Tags: plugins, updates

I am running WP multisite with about 80 sites.

I can see from my server's directory structure the presence of only one directory for ../wp-content/plugins/*

Each of the plugins I have installed is listed in the plugins directory one time. (Makes sense)

My question is, when there is an update to be installed on any particular plugin, does it matter what site I am logged into on the admin side when I do the plugin update?

For example:

- can I update the plug while in the Admin Panel UI for any site?
- should I be at the base site (that is, the first one I installed) and perform the update from there?
- should I be in the Network Admin UI (Network Admin > Plugins) to perform the update form there?
- or does it simply not matter?

Thanks for shedding some light on this process. I'm a bit foggy on the behind the scenes aspect of it.

Comment: Only [Super Admins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Super_Admin) should be able to update plugins for a MS install which means that it doesn't matter what site you're on and every site using that plugin will have it updated automatically.

Comment: @Welcher if that's the case maybe you can write an answer and get some upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Only [Super Admins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Super_Admin) should be able to update plugins for a MS install which means that it doesn't matter what site you're on and every site using that plugin will have it updated automatically.